# How can I implement meteor score when evaluating a model when using the meteor_score module from nltk?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, metrics

I currently have 2 files, reference.txt and model.txt. These two text files contain original captions and generated captions after training.
Can I simply do the following to obtain the meteor score:

```
score = nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score(reference, model)
print(np.mean(meteor_score))
```

I have also looked to https://github.com/tylin/coco-caption but I have no clue how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start by defining terms

Reference: The actual text/ground truth. If there are multiple people generating the ground truth for same datapoint you will have multiple references and all of them are assumed to be correct

hypothesis: The candidate/predicted.

Lets say the 2 people look at an image and they caption

- this is an apple
- that is an apple

Now your model looked at the image and predicted

- an apple on this tree

You can calculate the meteor_score of how good the prediction was using

```
print (nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score(
    ["this is an apple", "that is an apple"], "an apple on this tree"))
print (nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score(
    ["this is an apple", "that is an apple"], "a red color fruit"))
```

Output:

```
0.6233062330623306
0.0
```

In your case you have to read `reference.txt` into a list and similarly model predicitons into another. Now you have to get the `meteor_score` for each line in the first list with the each line in the second list and finally take a mean.