# MT: Calculating METEOR Score of two different files

Tags: python, nlp, evaluation, machine-translation, fairseq

For an Machine Translation evaluation I need to calculate the METEOR score between the translation output file and the reference file.

I already found this question [How can I implement meteor score when evaluating a model when using the meteor_score module from nltk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778133/how-can-i-implement-meteor-score-when-evaluating-a-model-when-using-the-meteor-s), but it was not helpful.

- Is there any official Python package or Github repository for the calculation of the METEOR score you would recommend?
- How to calculate the METEOR between the reference file and the output translation file?

Answer (score 0):

I found out you have to download METEOR from [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~alavie/METEOR/index.html#Download](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ealavie/METEOR/index.html#Download) .

For calculating the METEOR Score you need Java as well.

Run the following command to compare the reference and the test file and to get the METEOR score:

```
java -Xmx2G -jar meteor-1.5.jar test-file reference-file -l de
```

This page is well documented: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~alavie/METEOR/README.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ealavie/METEOR/README.html)